# Creating an SQL query to show clients owing payments

Tags: sql-server

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to produce a query that displays the client names, contact numbers, email addresses and total unpaid job costs of any clients who have a total (sum) of at least $500 in unpaid jobs.

I then have to order the results so that the largest amount owing is at the top.

So far I have come up with this query

```
SELECT 
  j.job_id, 
  c.name + c.surname, 
  c.phone, 
  c.email_address, 
  SUM(jt.cost * (DATEDIFF(mi, timestart, timecomplete)))
FROM client as c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN job AS j ON c.tax_file_number = c.tax_file_number
LEFT OUTER JOIN job_type AS jt ON j.jobtype_id = jt.jobtype_id
WHERE SUM(jt.cost * (DATEDIFF(mi, timecomplete, timestart) > 500
ORDER BY SUM(jt.cost * (DATEDIFF(mi, timecomplete, timestart))) DESC;
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: the result i get isMsg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 147
Incorrect syntax near '>'.

Comment: WHERE SUM(jt.cost * (DATEDIFF(mi, timecomplete, timestart))) > 500

Comment: i added the parenthesis and it came up with this error

Comment: Msg 147, Level 15, State 1, Line 147
An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Comment: you can not use sum in where condition use sub query instead of sum method...

Comment: what table are timestart and timecomplete? job?

Comment: also, sum does not make sense with no GROUP BY

Comment: yes unfortunately my subquery skills arent great 
and timestart, timecomplete are part of the job_type table

Comment: declare _sum int,
set _sum= (select SUM(jt.cost * (DATEDIFF(mi, timecomplete, timestart))) from job_type)

SELECT 
  j.job_id, 
  c.name + c.surname, 
  c.phone, 
  c.email_address, 
  SUM(jt.cost * (DATEDIFF(mi, timestart, timecomplete)))
FROM client as c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN job AS j ON c.tax_file_number = c.tax_file_number
LEFT OUTER JOIN job_type AS jt ON j.jobtype_id = jt.jobtype_id
WHERE _sum > 500

Comment: add above SQL in your procedure where _sum is calculating in other query...

Comment: @kuldeep 
thank you for the advice 
will keep working on it

Comment: @Kuldeep - this is not really a comment, should be in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing here since your requirements are not clear, but I think you want this:

```
WITH jobinfo as
(
   SELECT j.client_id, SUM(jt.cost * (DATEDIFF(mi, timecomplete, timestart))) as cost
   FROM job as j
   JOIN job_type as jt ON j.jobtype_id = jt.jobtype_id
   GROUP BY j.client_id
)
SELECT 
  c.client_id,
  c.name + c.surname, 
  c.phone, 
  c.email_address, 
  j.cost
FROM client as c 
JOIN jobinfo j ON c.client_id= j.client_id
WHERE j.cost > 500
ORDER BY j.cost DESC
```

Comment: @josh - When testing you can take the sub-query from the jobinfo CTE and run that in analyzer and see if it gives expected results.

Comment: keep getting blocked 
see tax_file_number is not found in the job table 
it is only found in the client table

Comment: so i made a few adjustments to your code 
and it produces a table 
unfortunately its all blank 
my code adjustments :

Comment: WITH jobinfo as
(
   SELECT c.tax_file_number, SUM(jt.cost * (DATEDIFF(mi, timestart, timecomplete))) as cost
   FROM job as j
   Join client as c
   on j.client_id = c.client_id 
   JOIN job_type as jt ON j.jobtype_id = jt.jobtype_id
   GROUP BY tax_file_number
)

Comment: SELECT 
  j.job_id, 
  c.tax_file_number,
  c.name + c.surname client_name, 
  c.phone, 
  c.email_address, 
  jt.cost
FROM client as c
JOIN jobinfo jo ON c.tax_file_number = c.tax_file_number
join job as j on j.job_id = j.client_id
JOIN job_type as jt ON j.jobtype_id = jt.jobtype_id  
WHERE jt.cost > 500
ORDER BY jt.cost DESC

Comment: sorry had to break it in half

Comment: @josh -- PLEASE USE THE EXACT query above.  Your joins are wrong, you need two tables in them and you CAN'T have job_ids in the final BECAUSE it is grouped by client id -- it aggregates them all into a sum.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare _sum int,
```

set _sum= (select SUM(jt.cost * (DATEDIFF(mi, timecomplete, timestart))) from job_type) SELECT j.job_id, c.name + c.surname, c.phone, c.email_address, SUM(jt.cost * (DATEDIFF(mi, timestart, timecomplete))) FROM client as c LEFT OUTER JOIN job AS j ON c.tax_file_number = c.tax_file_number LEFT OUTER JOIN job_type AS jt ON j.jobtype_id = jt.jobtype_id WHERE _sum > 500

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following.  Aggregate function (`SUM`, `COUNT`, etc) are not allowed on the `WHERE` clause, you should use `HAVING` for those.

```
SELECT 
  j.job_id, 
  c.name + c.surname, 
  c.phone, 
  c.email_address, 
  SUM(jt.cost * (DATEDIFF(mi, timestart, timecomplete)))
FROM client as c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN job AS j ON a.tax_file_number = c.tax_file_number
LEFT OUTER JOIN job_type AS jt ON j.jobtype_id = jt.jobtype_id
HAVING SUM(jt.cost * (DATEDIFF(mi, timecomplete, timestart) > 500
ORDER BY SUM(jt.cost * (DATEDIFF(mi, timecomplete, timestart))) DESC;
```

**EDIT:**
Fixed `ON a.tax_file_number = c.tax_file_number`

Comment: -1 - `ON c.tax_file_number = c.tax_file_number` is not a valid join for table j

Comment: Thanks @Hogan. I did not noticed the error on the question query.