# Stuck on queries in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hey guys do you mind checking if I'm doing this correctly? I'm stuck on this question:

Produce a query to display the accountant name and their average job cost (rounded to two decimal places) for all accountants who have an average job cost that is higher than the average job cost for all jobs.

```
SELECT 
  a.name + a.surname, 
  SUM(jt.cost * (DATEDIFF(mi, time_complete, time_start))) % SUM(job_id) AS average_job_cost
FROM accountant AS a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN job AS j ON a.staff_id = j.staff_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN job_type AS jt ON jt.job_type_id = j.job_type_id
WHERE average_job_cost > (SELECT SUM(jt.cost * (DATEDIFF(mi, time_complete, time_start))) % SUM(job_id);
```

Comment: As one observation, your subquery does not contain a `from` clause, leading me to doubt that this will work.

Comment: Are you and Josh [on the same course](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19755097/73226)?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: yeah, it's group work. and we're stuck big time. haha

Comment: @user2949666 - take a look at my answer for josh's question, using a CTE will help here.  Select all the averages and then join to that CTE

Comment: @MartinSmith ROFL. Nice catch! Looks like School Homework to me too!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (edited from original to use client_id as found on other question)

```
WITH jobinfo as
(
   SELECT j.client_id, AVG(jt.cost * (DATEDIFF(mi, timecomplete, timestart))) as avgerage
   FROM job as j
   JOIN job_type as jt ON j.jobtype_id = jt.jobtype_id
   GROUP BY j.client_id
), avgAll AS
(
   SELECT AVG(average) as aall
   FROM jobinfo
)
SELECT 
  c.client_id,
  c.name + c.surname, 
  c.phone, 
  c.email_address, 
  j.avgerage
FROM client as c 
JOIN jobinfo j ON c.client_id= j.client_id
WHERE j.avgerage > (SELECT aall FROM avgALL)
ORDER BY j.avgerage DESC
```